# ros_comm indigo trusty tahr

Tags: ros, ros-comm, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed ros on ubuntu 14.04 with sudo apt-get install ros-indigo*

How can I install ros_comm from github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/indigo-devel ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156411/ros_comm-indigo-trusty-tahr/) by [goupil35000](https://answers.ros.org/users/7096/goupil35000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can simply follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source) guide. Make sure to follow the ros_comm part, when I tried it last week the other two weren't live yet.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2014-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0